# Create user without calling manager create_user method in Django

Tags: django, field, required, django-users

From what I have read, the `create_user` (and `create_superuser`) method receives required parameters only. I;m trying to create an user whit required and non-required parameters, by adding another argument to the create_user function I've got errors.
I did override the User model from auth module, so MyUser is an `AbstractBaseUser` and its manager is a `BaseUserManager`.
I have a view where a pretend to create the user with required and non-required fields, should I override init?

Comment: cf Django docs : "The extra_fields keyword arguments are passed through to the User’s __init__ method to allow setting arbitrary fields on a custom User model" => it should work, what is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

The `create_user` function is just a shortcut. You should instantiate a user with `user = MyUser(field1=arg1, field2=arg2)`, remember to use the `set_password` function for the password, and call `user.save()`.

There is a generic `create` method as well that accepts all fields available on your user model, but I don't know if it handles passwords correctly.